# How to change a specific HTML string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my HTML code:

```
<th>
    Click<br/>
    <img class="magnifier" height="66" src="../Images/magnifier-zoom.png" width="75"><br/>
    To Enlarge
</th>
```

I have a jQuery script that when clicked it toggles an `enlarge` class, so when someone clicks to enlarge I want to change the `enlarge` **word** to `shrink` would there be any simple way of doing this in jQuery?

Or do you guys think I am better off having 2 `<div>`'s or even `<span>` elements and toggle the display of each element?

Comment: having two separate elements, toggling display, would probably be easier to maintain/read, since clicking each performs two different (separate) actions. Similar amount of coding for each approach, it's all preference....Jonathan Sampson's answer is probably what you're talking about tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous ways to do this. You could leverage pseudo-element content, do string manipulation with JavaScript, and more. In the end, the best approach is to probably just toggle the visibility of a couple nested elements:

I've placed a default "shrink" class on my `td` element. Within, I have a couple span elements customized with explicit `data-do` attributes indicating the purpose of each:

```
<td class="shrink"> 
    Click to 
    <span data-do="enlarge">Enlarge</span>
    <span data-do="shrink">Shrink</span>
    <img src="..." />
</td>
```

We target the `data-do` attributes that are nested within elements that have corresponding classes, and we disable the display of these elements:

```
.shrink  [data-do='shrink'],
.enlarge [data-do='enlarge'] { 
    display: none;
}
```

In order to toggle the class of the `td` element, we bind up some simple jQuery:

```
$("td").on("click", function () {
   $(this).toggleClass("shrink enlarge"); 
});
```

Anytime a `td` is clicked (you can make the selector specific to a single `td`), we add toggle the "shrink" and "enlarge" classes. If "enlarge" was present to begin with, it is removed; otherwise it will be added. The same goes for "shrink".

Comment: Gotta love the keywords in that description: *toggles* - *class* :)

Comment: OP needs to change wording "enlarge" to "shrink" and vise versa

Comment: @YuriyGalanter -- This will do that, assuming one of the classes is set at page load.

Comment: OP is asking how to change the text of the element, not its class.

Comment: @tymeJV don't see how. *"I want to change the enlarge word to shrink"*

Comment: @BrianGlaz I think the OP is asking both how to change the class, and the text. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter -- My bad, the **text** ! -- Missed that, just add `var text = $(this).hasClass("shrink") ? "shrink" : "enlarge"; //set the text then`

Comment: $(this).before($('<img>').text("Shrink: ")); can be added to the above answer

Comment: I do like the `toggleClass` idea... I think I will end up just creating 2 `<span>`s and toggling their visibility, but for now I am going to try everything and see what works best.

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML to

```
<th>
    <div>Click</div>
    <img class="magnifier" height="66" src="../Images/magnifier-zoom.png" width="75">
    <div>To Enlarge</div>
</th>
```

To have elements instead of text nodes.

Then you can do simple:

```
$('.magnifier').click(function() {

    var $next = $(this).next();

    $next.text($next.text() == 'To Enlarge' ? 'To Shrink' : 'To Enlarge');

})
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B7GDQ/**

Comment: what about instead of all separate div's you used a span?

Comment: DIVs keep elements with text that need changing separate and easy to access. Them being block elements make each item appear under each other like in the original `<br>` design. Could you please explain how a span would work?

Comment: Thats what I was asking you. Would there be anyway to create `<span class='action'>` and then check it's text to change?

Comment: My apologies, you mean instead of bottom DIV use a SPAN - that would hold "To Enlarge" or "To Shrink" action? Or a separate SPAN?

Comment: I mean instead of the bottom DIV use a SPAN

Comment: Definetely, just make sure to set it's display style to block if you want it to appear below the image: http://jsfiddle.net/B7GDQ/1/ when the class is assigned to that span - you don't even have to use `.next()` to locate it: http://jsfiddle.net/B7GDQ/2/

Answer (score 0):

This is the direct answer to your questions, although not the best method:

```
$(".magnifier").on("click", function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass('enlarge')) {
    $(this).removeClass('enlarge');
    this.parentNode.lastChild.textContent = 'To Enlarge'
  }else{
    $(this).addClass('enlarge');
    this.parentNode.lastChild.textContent = 'To Shrink';
  }
});
```

---

The ideal method would be to use pseudo elements:

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/vivekvasani/pen/ouzHF)

HTML:

```
<div class="magnifier">
  Click<br/>
  <img height="66" src="../Images/magnifier-zoom.png" width="75"><br/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.magnifier::after {
  content: 'To Enlarge';
}
.magnifier.enlarge::after {
  content: 'To Shrink';
}
```

JS:

```
$(".magnifier").on("click", function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('enlarge');
});
```